# R vs Python differences in floating point resolution : Is it possible to set Python act like R?

Tags: python, r, floating-point, linear-algebra, floating-accuracy

I am working on a personal project involving the manipulation of linear algebra concepts.
This project involves, in the first instance, replicating (translating) an R (64bit version) code into a Python code.
The problem described here attempts to reproduce the problem I am facing.

Based on some internet search I have done, this problem seems to be related to the handling of decimal numbers with great precision.

Here are the two pieces of code:

**R code:**

```
library(base)

# load, subsetting and convert df to matrix
df <- read.csv('hansen99.csv') 
arr <- data.matrix(df[c(4:20)])

# crossprod leads to a square matrix and do inverse calculation
A <- t(arr) %*% arr # crossprod leads to a square matrix
A_inv <- solve(A)   

# affichage avec 100 décimales
sprintf("%.100f",A_inv[1,1]) 
# '0.0023559636604639148764472889041599046322517096996307373046875000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
```

**Python code:**

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as npla
import pandas as pd

# load, subsetting and convert df to array
df = pd.read_csv('hansen99.csv')
arr = df.iloc[:, 3:21].values

# crossprod leads to a square matrix and do inverse calculation
A = np.transpose(arr) @ arr
A_inv = npla.inv(A)

# affichage avec 100 décimales
"{:.100f}".format(A_inv[0,0])
# '0.0023559636604639157438090268925634518382139503955841064453125000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
```

**A_inv** is therefore the inverse of a given matrix **A** (csv file). If I take the first element of this matrix and print it with 100 decimal places, I obtain :

```
R      : '0.0023559636604639*1*48764472889041599046322517096996307373046875000000000000000000000000000000000000000'

Python : '0.0023559636604639*1*57438090268925634518382139503955841064453125000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
```

We can see that after the **17th decimal** place (between stars) the sequence of numbers displayed is different between R and Python.

I've done some research and it seems to be related to the decimal resolution of types.

In python, I have the command for the float64 type (Don't know how to get it in R):

```
np.finfo(np.float64)
# finfo(resolution=1e-15, min=-1.7976931348623157e+308, max=1.7976931348623157e+308, dtype=float64)
```

**Notes**:

This difference does not seem to be related to a difference between the respective functions of the two languages. I called the R functions in Python and the Python functions in R to make sure.

**Data**:

If you are interested in data follow https://github.com/ceteuf/PSTR/tree/main/data/hansen99.csv

**Questions**:

**1)** What do you think is the reason for this difference? (need clarification, and possibly good resources to learn more)

**2)** Is it possible, by modifying a configuration or whatever, to reproduce exactly the same result and behaviour as R?

**2b)** Or was I completely wrong? In that case, do you have any leads?

Comment: In R, you can find resolution/precision information in [`.Machine`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/zMachine.html).

Comment: Hello, I know this method but I can't see the equivalent resolution item as in Python.

Comment: Sorry, I was going off the mention of *"not found for R"*. 64-bit work might be done with the [`bit64`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bit64/index.html) package, though its compatibility in all functions/packages is incomplete at best.

Comment: `.Machine$double.xmax` ?

Comment: @r2evans Ty, Strangely I forgot to check if it could have something to do with R's version. I'll look into it.

Comment: Ty,  @Onyambu, I'll look further into what ".Machine" documentation says

Comment: @r2evans I have edited the misleading "not found for R"

Comment: They should both be using 64-bit IEEE floats. Whatever the problem is, I doubt that it is one of *precision*. It could be simply one of *display*. Without using the `decimal` module in Python, something like `"%.100f"` is just pointless. IEEE floats don't have that much precision in either R or Python.

Comment: Good point, @JohnColeman, my `bit64` reference was misplaced, that's 64-bit integers only.